# Can you add new Parent Projects to TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to add new parent projects to TeamCity?

When I add a new Project, I am prompted to select the parent project. I only see `<Root project>` and I can't see any way of adding a new Parent Project.

When I add a project, I get the following:

[image: Parent Project]

I assume you can add Parent Project, otherwise, why give the choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll try to explain how it works. The project structure is like a tree. **There is only one root**, but you can nest projects, so once you've created a project you'll be able to select it as the parent for another new project. Consider this structure:

```
<Root project>
|- Parent Project A
   |- Child Project 1
   |- Child Project 2
|- Parent Project B
   |- Child Project 3
```

In this case, you would see `<Root project>`, `Parent Project A`, and `Parent Project B` in the drop down for selecting the parent project. If you wanted to add another parent project, then you'd select root. Otherwise, you would select the parent project for which you want to create a new child.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise you could only have the out of the box `<Root project>` as the topmost project.

Comment: That's why it is called "root".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology_used_in_trees

Answer (score 2):

Do you already have some projects in your TC? If not, first create a project Foo under the Root; then you can create a project Bar under Foo.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have projects logically separated. If you can't add new parent projects yourself, `<Root project>` seems redundant.

Comment: It's like the filesystem. For now all you have the root, `/`. You can't put `Bar` under `/Foo` (to produce `/Foo/Bar`) until you've created `/Foo` first.